# Sending Location with SMS Message Issue?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, sms, google-play-services

Quick question, I've got my class setup and my SMS messages send and I've got no errors.I am trying to send my location as a part of the SMS message as a google maps link. The issue is that my messages are sending but the location link is not going through? However the file has no errors and the messaging works.

Any ideas? Also I've included "access fine location" in my Manifest file.

Class:

```
Button btnSendSMS;
EditText txtPhoneNo;
EditText txtMessage;
String message;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_sms);
    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);


    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
            String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
            displayLocation();

            if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
                sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


    private void displayLocation(){
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, new LocationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {}
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {}
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {}
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {}
        });
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        message+="https://www.google.co.id/maps/@"+latitude+","+longitude;
}





//---sends a SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, Home.class), 0);
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);


    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager smms = android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.getDefault();
    smms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?? You've given us literally no details about what the issue is.

Comment: @tnw My bad just edited that. basically my messaging works but the google location link does not go through with my message but there are no errors? and the app works... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `message` variable which is set in `displayLocation()` is a member variable of your activity (declared at the top of your code). So when you do:

```
String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
displayLocation();
```

That local variable `message` is not modified.

What you can do is return the string from `displayLocation` and add it to the message:

```
private String displayLocation() {
    //...
    return "https://www.google.co.id/maps/@"+latitude+","+longitude;
}

String message = txtMessage.getText().toString() + displayLocation();
if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
//...
```

And I believe you should remove the `message` class member variable if you aren't using it anywhere else.

Comment: ...Sorry bit of unsure how to do it could you please explain how I can modify the variable to make it work? Bit new too all of this.